# Three.js: Rendering LineSegments Wireframe with RawShaderMaterial

Tags: javascript, three.js

I’m working on a [scene](https://bl.ocks.org/duhaime/b50c3230238ff88c1779cef1fe02f7a7) that renders some `THREE.LineSegments` as a wireframe. I now want to slowly move the vertices in the LineSegments material (this object is named `warehouse` in the scene above), but I can't figure out how to render my LineSegments wireframe in a `THREE.RawShaderMaterial`.

The easiest way I’ve found to slowly move vertices is to use a `RawShaderMaterial`, provide both currentPosition and targetPosition attributes for that geometry, and use a transitionPercent uniform that controls the mixture of each position in the rendered vertex position:

```
vec3 pos = mix(currentPosition, targetPosition, transitionPercent)
```

However, when I try to use a RawShaderMaterial for the warehouse in the scene above, I lose the wireframe geometry on the warehouse, as setting wireframe = true on a RawShaderMaterial doesn’t have the same effect as it does on the LineBasicMaterial.

I tried a few things to create a wireframe geometry that I could pass to my RawShaderMaterial, like:

```
var g1 = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
g1.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
var g2 = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(g1),
    wireframe = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(g2),
    geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(wireframe);
```

But all attempts have failed to unlock the secret.

Does anyone know how I can render the warehouse object above as a wireframe using a RawShaderMaterial? I’d be super grateful for any help others can offer on this question!

P.S. I posted this in the [THREE.js discussion page](https://discourse.threejs.org) but am cross-posting here to get more eyes on the question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved with the following:

```
var g2 = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(geometry);
var wireframeGeometry = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(g2);
wireframeGeometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
wireframeGeometry.addAttribute('target', new THREE.BufferAttribute(targets, 3));
wireframeGeometry.addAttribute('alpha', new THREE.BufferAttribute(alphas, 1));
wireframeGeometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
warehouse = new THREE.LineSegments(wireframeGeometry, shaderMaterial);
shaderMaterial.wireframe = true;
scene.add(warehouse);
```